# How to increase video memory in libvirt/KVM gui?

Tags: virtual-machines, kvm-virtualization, libvirt

In the 'Virtual Hardware details', it lists the model as 'cirrus' with 9MB of RAM. The RAM field cannot be changed, but how to increate the video RAM? My host OS is RH6 and gust OS is Fedora16.

EDIT: From guest OS, when I run `xvinfo` it displays 'no adaptors present'.

I was trying to play a video using gstreamers xvimagesink plugin (XFree86 video output plugin using Xv extension). The problem is that xvimagesink is using hardware acceleration for video performance and hence the error `Could not initialize Xv output`.

I guess I'll have to configure hardware acceleration for the guest.

Comment: What's your outer problem? Why do you want to increase the video memory?

Comment: can you explain the use case? 9Mb of RAM, or 900 - will not make a difference if you want to play games in the VM

Comment: The outer problem is that inside my guest I run `xvinfo` which displays 'no adaptors present'. I was attempting to play a video using gstreamer. How would I go about configuring my guest to support that?

Comment: If you are using qxl, and spawning using CLI, then use: -vga qxl -global qxl-vga.vram_size=$SIZE_IN_BYTES

Answer (score 5):

Should be as easy as `virsh edit DOMAIN` and changing `vram` attribute of `/domain/devices/video/model`:

```
...
<video>
  <model type='cirrus' vram='9216' heads='1'/>                                                            
  <address type='pci' domain='0x0000' bus='0x00' slot='0x02' function='0x0'/>
</video>
...
```

Comment: What is the `cirrus` type, I am using nvidia card and host applies the nouveau driver.

Comment: @Dejan I think you misunderstand.  KVM and QEMU virtualize hardware.  They simulate a video card for the guest OS.  Without special exceptions, a guest OS cannot direct access any components of a host computer.  As for what Cirrus means, it means your guest virtual machine has been told it has a Cirrus Logic video card.  Other options include std (SVGA video), vmware (VMware video adapter - s3 Trident II, IIRC),  qxl (Para-virtualized video), of these QXL is generally the best choice - once you have the drivers ready.  Good luck!